# LeftRotate failing in AVL Tree at the last point when entering numbers from 1 - 10

Tags: c, avl-tree

I am trying to add numbers in AVL Tree where the node takes (key, value). When entering numbers from (0,0) to (10,10) in the for loop, the code fails when it tries to enter the number (10,10).

Following is the code to insert the node in the tree:

```
int insert_in_tree_q5(struct AVLTreeNode **node, int key, int value){

    //AVLTreeNode *newNode = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
    // if the tree is empty
    if(*node == NULL){
        *node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
    }
    if(key != (*node)->key){
        // insert on left if the data in the key is less than the data in the node.
        if (key<(*node)->key){
            insert_in_tree_q5(&(*node)->left, key,value);
        }
        // insert on right if the data in the key is greater than the data in the node.
        else if(key>(*node)->key)
        {
            insert_in_tree_q5(&(*node)->right, key,value);
        }
        // Update height of the ancestor node
        (*node)->height = 1 + max(height((*node)->left), height((*node)->right));
        // check balance to see if this node became unbalanced
        int balance = getBalance(*node);

        //First case to balance the unbalanced node
        // Left Left case
        if(balance>1 && key<(*node)->left->key){
            *node = rightRotate(*node);
        }
        // Right Right Case
        if (balance < -1 && key > (*node)->right->key)
            *node = leftRotate(*node);

        // Left Right Case
        if (balance > 1 && key > (*node)->left->key)
        {
            (*node)->left =  leftRotate((*node)->left);
            *node = rightRotate(*node);
        }

        // Right Left Case
        if (balance < -1 && key < (*node)->right->key)
        {
            (*node)->right = rightRotate((*node)->right);
            *node = leftRotate(*node);
        }
    }
    else if(key == (*node)->key){
        if (value<(*node)->value){
            insert_in_tree_q5(&(*node)->left, key,value);
        }
        // insert on right if the data in the key is greater than the data in the node.
        else if(value>(*node)->value)
        {
            insert_in_tree_q5(&(*node)->right, key,value);
        }
        // Update height of the ancestor node
        (*node)->height = 1 + max(height((*node)->left), height((*node)->right));
        // check balance to see if this node became unbalanced
        int balance = getBalance(*node);

        //First case to balance the unbalanced node
        // Left Left case
        if(balance>1 && value<(*node)->left->value){
            *node =rightRotate(*node);
        }
        // Right Right Case
        if (balance < -1 && value > (*node)->right->value)
            *node =leftRotate(*node);

        // Left Right Case
        if (balance > 1 && value > (*node)->left->value)
        {
            (*node)->left =  leftRotate((*node)->left);
            *node =rightRotate(*node);
        }

        // Right Left Case
        if (balance < -1 && value < (*node)->right->value)
        {
            (*node)->right = rightRotate((*node)->right);
            *node =leftRotate(*node);
        }
    }else if(key == (*node)->key && value == (*node)->value){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;

}
```

The code for Left Rotate is :

```
struct AVLTreeNode* leftRotate(struct AVLTreeNode *x){
    struct AVLTreeNode *y = x->right;
    struct AVLTreeNode *T2 = y->left;

    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    //  Update heights
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;

    // Return new root
    return y;
}
```

The way I am entering the values in the tree is :

```
int InsertNode(AVLTree *T, int k, int v)
{
    //put your code here
    int returnedValue = insert_in_tree_q5(&T->root, k, v);
    if(returnedValue==0){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
tree4=newAVLTree();
    j=InsertNode(tree4, 10, 10);
    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        j=InsertNode(tree4, i, i);
        if (j==0) printf("(%d, %d) already exists\n", i, i);
    }
```

The signature of the AVLTreeNode and AVLTree is:

```
typedef struct AVLTreeNode {
    int key; //key of this item
    int  value;  //value (int) of this item
    int height; //height of the subtree rooted at this node
    struct AVLTreeNode *parent; //pointer to parent
    struct AVLTreeNode *left; //pointer to left child
    struct AVLTreeNode *right; //pointer to right child
} AVLTreeNode;

AVLTree *newAVLTree()
{
    AVLTree *T;
    T = malloc(sizeof (AVLTree));
    assert (T != NULL);
    T->size = 0;
    T->root = NULL;
    return T;
}
```

PS: If the item (k,v) already exists, it should return 0 else add it to the tree and return 1.
Any ideas as to why it accepts all the values till (9,9) but fails at (10,10) with error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)"

Comment: you have a problem or logic in your tests in `insert_in_tree_q5` see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the item (k,v) already exists, it should return 0 else add it to the tree and return 1

in `insert_in_tree_q5` you do :

```
if(*node == NULL){
    *node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
}
if(key != (*node)->key){
  ...CASE A
}
else if(key == (*node)->key){
    ...CASE B
} else if(key == (*node)->key && value == (*node)->value){
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

the case `else if(key == (*node)->key && value == (*node)->value)` is never reach because just before you do `else if(key == (*node)->key)`, you need to reverse their order.

For me when `(*node == NULL)` you do not have to continue too

Note you already know that `if(key != (*node)->key)` is false so to test the equality in the two next tests is useless

Finaly your code must be :

```
if(*node == NULL){
    *node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
}
else if(key != (*node)->key){
  ...CASE A
}
else if( value == (*node)->value){
    return 0;
}
else {
    ...CASE B
} 
return 1;
```

---

In

```
int InsertNode(AVLTree *T, int k, int v)
{
    //put your code here
    int returnedValue = insert_in_tree_q5(&T->root, k, v);
    if(returnedValue==0){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

because `insert_in_tree_q5` only returns 0 or 1 *InsertNode* can be simplified to be just

```
int InsertNode(AVLTree *T, int k, int v)
{
    return insert_in_tree_q5(&T->root, k, v);
}
```